# Incorrect variable value incrementing

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int ch, lower, upper = 0;
        printf("Enter a line of text: \n");
        while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (islower(ch)) {
                ch = toupper(ch);
                ++upper;
        } else if (isupper(ch)) {
                ch = tolower(ch);

                printf("Looking at lower: %d\n", lower);
                ++lower;
                printf("Looking at lower: %d\n", lower);
        }
        putchar(ch);
        }
        printf("Hello\n");
        printf("\nRead %d characters in total. %d converted to upper-case, %d to lower-case.", upper+lower, upper, lower);
}
```

For some reason the upper variable is being set correctly, but can't work out why lower is giving an erroneous value. E.g. If I type in 'Football' it says 4195825 converted to lower-case, where the actual output should be 1.

I can't see where I'm going wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't initialized `lower`. It's value is indeterminate.

#### C11: 6.7.9 Initialization (p10):

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
>   indeterminate.

Initialize it to `0`.

```
int ch, lower = 0, upper = 0;
```

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. If I do int ch, lower, upper; It gives the same output.

Comment: Yes this is the issue. I quoted the standard.

Comment: Oh sorry yeah you are right, but how come the upper variable works correctly if I do int ch, lower, upper; but the lower variable does not?

Comment: Indirectly, your program invokes undefined behavior. You may either get expected or unexpected output. Nothing can be said.

Comment: Interesting.. is there anywhere I can read more about this random behaviour?

Comment: You can read from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and [c-faq](http://www.c-faq.com/ansi/undef.html).